# How to convert input text into keywords (no autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, html, css

So whenever I type anything in that box and press space it should get converted in to a keyword. check the attached image of StackOverflow-

[image]

I tried searching GitHub, but the example over there is vast and it's confusing, nothing like I want, which is short and similar to StackOverflow. Any idea how I can achieve it ?-

[image]

```css
#location{
 margin-top: 25px; 
 margin-left: 25px;
 font: 25px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}



#copykat_3 {

 
    font-size: 1.1em;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 border: none;
 padding: 0.7em 0.9em;
 outline: none;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -o-border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 75px;
 margin: 20px 10px 10px;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #4290c8;

 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
</div>
<p id="location">Locations you can provide</p>



</div>

<div>

  <input style="margin-left: 102px; type=" text " id="copykat_2 "  "class="textbox" value="Please type locations" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'locations';}">


  <input type="submit" id="copykat_3" value="Add" style="margin-left: 2px;">
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Turn off `autocomplete`?

Comment: When i type a keyword, let's say Apple and press space to type another word, Apple should be converted into a keyword with all that highlight and a small cross.

Comment: Something like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) ??

Comment: Chosen plugin is the best choice

Comment: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/  - something like this ! check the demo part.